# Why is the first column in all the rows in my 2d array being given the same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using javascript to populate an array when the page is loaded (every cell gets the value 'False') and then I use another javascript function to put the value 'True' in a cell when someone clicks on the radio button the table cell. When the Submit button is pressed, the first column of every row has the value 'True'. I don't know why this is happening.

Here is the code I am using:

This gets run when the page is loaded:

```
function Start() {   
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      arr[i,j]="False" 
    }
  }
}
```

This gets run when someone clicks the radio button in the cell of the table on the page:

```
function myFunction(x,y) {
  arr[x,y]="True";
}
```

What is very strange is if I check the value of say arr[2,1] before  arr[x,y]="True" in myFunction, it shows "False", but if I check it after  arr[x,y]="True", it shows "True"!! It's not just row 2, it shows "True" for the first column for all the rows!

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `arr[i, j]` does not do what you think it does. You need `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: `arr[i,j]` is essentially the same as `arr[j]` as both expressions (`i` before, and `j` after the comma) are evaluated, but only the last one (`j`) will be used in the surrounding expression.

Comment: Where did you DECLARE `arr` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you’re encountering is likely due to a misunderstanding of how JavaScript handles array indices. In JavaScript, multidimensional arrays aren’t supported directly, and the syntax arr[i, j] doesn’t create a two-dimensional array.

When you do arr[i, j] = "False", JavaScript is actually computing the expression i, j using the comma operator, which evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand. So, arr[i, j] is essentially the same as arr[j], because that’s the last value in the comma operator.

As a result, arr[1,1], arr[2,1], arr[3,1], and so on all reference arr[1], and that’s why it seems like the first column is set to “True” for all rows.

Instead, you should be creating an array of arrays to simulate a two-dimensional structure. Here’s how you can modify your code:

```
// Define arr as a global variable, or within a scope accessible to your functions
let arr = [];

function Start() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = []; // Initialize each array within the array
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = "False"; // Note the use of [i][j] instead of [i,j]
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(x, y) {
  arr[x][y] = "True";
}
```

Note a few things here:

Array indices start at 0. So if you want ten rows and columns, your loop should start from 0 and go to less than 10 (which is indices 0 through 9).

When setting up the array, use arr[i] = [] to create a new array for each row and then fill it with “False” values.

In the myFunction, ensure you access the element with arr[x][y], which gets the yth value in the xth subarray, reflecting a two-dimensional structure.

Make sure you adjust your calls to myFunction accordingly; for example, if you have an event listener or an inline event like onclick, update the indices to match this zero-based array indexing system. If the radio buttons are correctly mapped to this revised code, it should solve the issue you’re experiencing.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked. But now I have a new problem. I am trying to write out the values in my array to a text file. My sub-routine for writing the values out into a text file appear to be caught up in an infinite loop. I will post a new question with that sub-routine. But thanks again for your help with this problem!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're trying to use a two-dimensional array in JavaScript to represent a table. Use square bracket notation(`arr[x][y]`) instead of comma notation(`arr[x,y]`)

**The meaning of `arr[x, y]`**

The meaning of `arr[x, y]` is not intended for two-dimensional array access in JavaScript. Instead, it's a `comma operator` that evaluates both x and y expressions and returns the result of the last expression, which is `y`. Therefore, `arr[x, y]` is equivalent to `arr[y]`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let x = 2;
let y = 3;
console.log(arr[x, y]);    // Output is 4
```

*Updated version.*

```js
function Start() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    arr[i] = []; // Create an array for each row
    for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = "False";
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(x, y) {
  arr[x][y] = "True";
}
```

Comment: You should enhance the "meaning of a[x,y]" by saying that "x,y" is an expression which returns "y". An example is great, but it does not really clearly answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Valuable one and I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-based in JavaScript, therefore the index for a first element in each dimension would be `0` and not `1`. And, as mentioned in the comments, you would need to apply a syntax like `arr[i][j]` in combination with *declaring* each sub-array first.

Below is a short snippet showing an alternative way of creating a 2D array with `false` values:

```js
const arr=Array(11).fill(0).map(_=>
            Array(10).fill(false));

// Now, change the first value in the third row to TRUE:
arr[2][0]=true;

// show the whole array:
console.log(arr);
```